# Jquery trigger another keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have keypress function and I want to fire tab Key event on pressing Up Arrow and Down Arrow key press something like this:

```
   if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        jQuery.event.trigger({ type: 'keyup', which: 9 });
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == 40) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        jQuery.event.trigger({ type: 'keyup', which: 9 });
    }
```

Comment: [`var e = $.Event('keyup');
        e.which = 9;
        $(this).trigger(e);`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kpdn3bkf/)